# text area color and delete the border when clicked

Tags: html, css, wordpress, forms, web

After I click on the input box, I have a border around it until I click on another element. I want to remove this border when I have clicked on it.

This is my code:

```css
.cf7b-group-text-582{
    border:1px solid blue;
}
.cf7b-group-text-582:hover{
    background-color:#0C71C3;
}
```

```html
<div class="cf7b-group-text-582">
  <p>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap" data-name="text-582">
      <input size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Betreff" value="" type="text" name="text-582" />
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

I have tried hover but I can not remove it as this is not the right way. I want the color to remain when I go over with mouse.

[image: box image]

thank you for your help

I try to use border:none/border:0 but doesnt work

Comment: Hard to understand that word salad, but I am guessing you are looking for [`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) ...?

Comment: Or [`:focus-within`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) if you don't want to apply this directly to the input field itself, but an ancestor.

Comment: yes thank you, im sorry for my english , is not my main language so , better if i use the translator

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what the problem is, but I hope the code below helps. When the input is clicked, it removes the border, when clicked elsewhere, it adds the border again.

```js
var input=document.getElementsByClassName("wpcf7-text")[0];
    var div=document.getElementsByClassName("cf7b-group-text-582")[0];

    input.addEventListener('click', function() {
        div.style.border="none";
    });

    input.onblur = function() {
        div.style.border = "1px solid blue";
    }
```

```css
.cf7b-group-text-582{
    border:1px solid blue;
}
.cf7b-group-text-582:hover{
    background-color:#0C71C3;
}
```

```html
<div class="cf7b-group-text-582">
  <p>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap" data-name="text-582">
      <input size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Betreff" value="" type="text" name="text-582" />
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
```